# Move LVM of PV1 to PV2

Tags: linux, partition, lvm

How do I move/merge LVM on sda3 to sda2? The problem is vg1-var and vg1-opt reside on both PVs, so a `pvmove` won't do the trick.

```
sda                          8:0    0   80G  0 disk
├─sda1                       8:1    0  300M  0 part /boot
├─sda2                       8:2    0   37G  0 part
│ ├─vg1-root         253:0    0    5G  0 lvm  /
│ ├─vg1-swap         253:1    0    4G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
│ ├─vg1-usr          253:2    0    8G  0 lvm  /usr
│ ├─vg1-home         253:4    0    2G  0 lvm  /home
│ ├─vg1-var          253:5    0  6.7G  0 lvm  /var
│ ├─vg1-tmp          253:6    0   10G  0 lvm  /tmp
│ └─vg1-opt          253:7    0    5G  0 lvm  /opt
└─sda3                       8:3    0 42.7G  0 part
  ├─vg1-var          253:5    0  6.7G  0 lvm  /var
  └─vg1-opt          253:7    0    5G  0 lvm  /opt
```

```
  PV         VG    Fmt  Attr PSize    PFree
  /dev/sda2  vg1   lvm2 a--    37.00g       0
  /dev/sda3  vg1   lvm2 a--   <42.70g   39.00g
```

Comment: It doesn't look like there's space for `var` and `opt` on `/dev/sda2`

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to merge these? It's certainly possible but LVM doesn't mind having two PVs either.

Comment: Mainly to follow the design we have set. Yes I understand there shouldn’t be an issue with this layout but well you know it would be nice to have it clean :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest method would be to attach a new drive temporarily and `pvmove /dev/sda3` over. That would allow you to grow `/dev/sda2` and move everything back.

If that's not possible, you'll have to shuffle the data within the drive you have. Due to alignment issues, adjacent PVs can usually not be merged directly, so you'll still be moving everything twice.

Your `/dev/sda3` is 42.7G large and has 39G free, so ~3.7G used. So you should be able to shrink `/dev/sda3` by 4G, in order to make a new `/dev/sda4` size 4G at end of disk:

```
pvresize /dev/sda3 --setphysicalvolumesize 37G
parted /dev/sda -- resizepart 3 -4G
parted /dev/sda -- mkpart primary -4G -1
```

Move all data to the new partition:

```
vgextend vg1 /dev/sda4
pvmove /dev/sda3
vgreduce vg1 /dev/sda3
```

Delete the now free `/dev/sda3` and grow `/dev/sda2` accordingly:

```
parted /dev/sda -- rm 3
parted /dev/sda -- resizepart 2 -4G
pvresize /dev/sda2
```

Move everything from `/dev/sda4` to the now large enough `/dev/sda2`:

```
pvmove /dev/sda4
vgreduce vg1 /dev/sda4
```

At this point, your VG only uses a single PV, `/dev/sda2`.

Delete the now free `/dev/sda4` and grow `/dev/sda2` again:

```
parted /dev/sda -- rm 4
parted /dev/sda -- resizepart 2 -1
pvresize /dev/sda2
```

Note these steps are very rough and might fail at some points, you'll have to adapt accordingly. The `parted` commands in particular should not be run blindly, always verify what's going on with `parted /dev/sda print free`, `vgs`, `lvs`, `pvs`, `lsblk`, ...

If there are no strong reasons to shuffle things around, I'd just leave as is. It's a lot of trouble for little benefit. Having multiple PVs also has advantages, such as additional metadata copies.

Comment: Just a dumb question. Does it need to be pvresize first before actually reducing the size of partition 3? Also the mkpart - is the ‘-4G’ a typo? And what does -1 do?

Comment: You need to `pvresize` shrink the PV before you shrink the partition. `-4G` means 4G from end of disk (so it will make room for a 4G partition). `-1` means end of disk (so, it will resize partition to full size). This works in your case since your partition happens to be the last one that goes to end of disk; if it was a partition somewhere in the middle, you'd have to do the math yourself to shrink the partition.

Comment: So in mkpart, a - means the size of the partition to create? And in resizepart, it means the size to shrink? I apologize for so many question. I get what the plan is; I just wanted to understand more on the parted part cause I mainly use fdisk.

Comment: the negative value just means "from end of disk". for details please refer to parted manual. if you're not familiar with parted, feel free to use any other partitioning software. just make sure the partition is not smaller than what you resized the PV to, so if you pvresize to 37G, the partition has to be 37 GiB at minimum. if you make the partition too small, LVM will complain and there is a risk of data loss.

Comment: also when resizing partitions, the start sector must not change; parted resizepart only changes the partition size. if another partition software requires you to delete and re-create the partition, you must take extra care to make it start at the same sector.