# Resize extended partition in the middle of the hdd with LVM

Tags: debian, partition, lvm

I would like to add a partition to use the free space (50GB) for LVM. The disk has been enlarged several times, which has created this partition chaos. How can I bring it back to order and use the free space?

```
# cfdisk /dev/sda
Disk: /dev/sda
Size: 200 GiB, 214748364800 bytes, 419430400 sectors
Label: dos, identifier: 0x000cc491

    Device      Boot   Start           End       Sectors      Size     Id Type
>>  /dev/sda1   *       2048        499711        497664      243M     83 Linux
    /dev/sda2         501758     167770111     167268354     79.8G      5 Extended
    └─/dev/sda5       501760     167770111     167268352     79.8G     8e Linux LVM
    /dev/sda3      167770112     209715199      41945088       20G     83 Linux
    /dev/sda4      209715200     314572799     104857600       50G     83 Linux
    Free space     314572800     419430399     104857600       50G
```

I tried to resize the extended parition first, so I can add a logical partition afterwards. But that doesn't work:

```
(parted) print                                                            
Model: VMware Virtual disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 215GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  256MB   255MB   primary   ext2         boot
 2      257MB   85.9GB  85.6GB  extended
 5      257MB   85.9GB  85.6GB  logical                lvm
 3      85.9GB  107GB   21.5GB  primary
 4      107GB   161GB   53.7GB  primary

(parted) resizepart                                                       
Partition number? 2                                                       
End?  [85.9GB]? 135.6                                                     
Error: Can't have the end before the start! (start sector=501758 length=-236914)
```

More informations:

```
# pvs
  PV         VG   Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree
  /dev/sda3  root lvm2 a--  20.00g    0 
  /dev/sda4  root lvm2 a--  50.00g    0 
  /dev/sda5  root lvm2 a--  79.76g    0 

# lvs
  LV     VG   Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  root   root -wi-ao---- 146.48g                                                    
  swap_1 root -wi-ao----   3.28g   

                                             
# vgs
  VG   #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  root   3   2   0 wz--n- 149.75g    0 

# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/dm-0       145G  129G  8.6G  94% /
udev             10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  9.2M  1.6G   1% /run
tmpfs           4.0G     0  4.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           4.0G     0  4.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1       228M   53M  164M  25% /boot
tmpfs           801M     0  801M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not grow existing partitions instead of adding new ones?

All your partitions are already part of your single LVM volume group, there's no need to add more, just grow what you have.

```
parted /dev/sda -- resizepart 4 100%
pvresize /dev/sda4
```

That should be the easiest way to solve it by far.

---

Resolving the existing partition ordering is a bit more involved. The simplest and safest way to resolve it would be to attach a new disk and migrate over.

Shuffling the data in place could possibly be done, I've described it before in [Move LVM of PV1 to PV2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/600286/30851). You can't apply this solution directly though due to your partition problem, and mapping the unpartitioned space with `losetup --offset` is risky as you can get the offset wrong, and it doesn't survive reboots.

Another option would be to convert to GPT partitions, where there is no distinction between primary vs. logical partitions so you can create as many as you want. However, doing so would render the system unbootable until you reinstall the boot loader. In case of Grub, you'd also have to create a bios_grub partition, which could be placed in 64s-2047s (before the first partition, ignoring alignment).

If `pvdisplay` shows `not usable x.y MiB` with `x >= 1`, you can also shrink each partition by 1 MiB and then convert between primary / logical partitions. The shrinking is necessary since msdos logical partition information is stored in gaps between those partitions. You currently have no such gaps between sda5-sda3-sda4 so they can't be mapped to logical partitions directly.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think of that! After `pvresize /dev/sda4` I run `lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/root-root` and `resize2fs -p /dev/mapper/root-root` and was done.

Comment: My error was that I was putting `100` without the `%`. Lol! Ty

Answer (score 1):

### general situation

That is not going to work. At least not without moving data around or making changes to the existing partitions.

If you have run out of primary partitions (as you have) then you can only add logical partitions. But those must be within the borders of the extended partition. So in order to make new space at the end of the block device available, the extended partition has to be at the end of it. Then you can move its high boundary to the new end of the device and create new logical partitions.

In theory it might be possible to extend the extended partition across primary partitions and create a fake logical partition (which must never be used for anything) which "covers" the primary partitions but as long as you do not know how all the partition tools react to that, it seems like a catastrophe waiting to happen so I would not encourage that.

### possible solution

If that would not cause problems then you could convert `sda3` and `sda4` to logical partitions. I have never done anything like that. And in order to work I guess you have to downsize `sda3`, `sda4`, and `sda5` slightly because there must be a 32K gap between logical partitions (because they are implemented as a chained list).

So you would have to

- downsize the filesystem in that partition by at least 32K
- move the high boundary of the partition by these 32K
- change the size of the extended partition and the primary partition entries (at best all at once).

The easiest approach is probably to dump the partition table with `sfdisk -d /dev/sda`, make the changes (`sda3` to `sda6`, `sda4` to `sda7`) and import this configuration (`sfdisk /dev/sda <modified_dump.sfdisk`).

An alternative would be to delete the partitions (which does not affect the data in them) and create them as logical partitions (with the partition tool of your choice) with the same start sector but the smaller size. You should boot from a different medium in order to do either.

**In any case: Store a copy of the original partition table on a different drive!**